# Не отображается текст БД (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Текст выводился до тех пор, пока не добавил кнопку, а после текст пропал. В тэге <ListView.ItemTemplate> сама кнопка. Нужно удалить элементы при нажатии на кнопку, а их даже не видно.

```
<Window x:Class="less2Design.UserPageWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:less2Design"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Title="App for users" Height="350" Width="600">
    <Grid Background="#ffdadada">
        <Border MinWidth="400" Margin="15" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="30" MaxWidth="550" CornerRadius="20">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="30" Color="LightGray" ShadowDepth="0" />
            </Border.Effect>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Админ панель" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 0 20" />
                <ListView x:Name="listOfAdmin" Margin="10">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Button Content="Удалить" x:Name="delButton" Click="delButton_Click"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так вы шаблон по умолчанию заменили своим собственным. Если вам нужен текст, то добавьте текстблок.

```xml
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    <Button Content="Удалить" x:Name="delButton" Click="delButton_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Советую научиться пользоваться привязками `Binding` и командами `ICommand`. Жить в WPF станет заметно легче.